# Learning MVC3, connection string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, connection-string

I'm learning MVC3 by covering the famous MusicStore tutorial http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/
The connection string used for EF code first is :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MusicStoreEntities"
    connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MvcMusicStore.sdf"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I would like to use my localhost SQL Server database (windows authentication) instead.  What would be the connection string for it to keep working correctly ? Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your DB name is `MusicStore`:

```
ConnectionString="Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=MusicStore; Integrated Security=True;"
Provider="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
<add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="DATA SOURCE =(Your Server Name); INITIAL CATALOG =MusicStore;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and have a look on

[Connection strings for SQL Server 2008](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Regards